# Best way to save NSMutableArray elements with content to Core Data entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmutablearray

I need to move only the array elements that have data to Core Data; this is my code (userPreferences is my CoreData entity):

```
    int count = [addlServicesArray count];

    //  move entire array elements with content to userPreferences
    userPreferences.aAddlSvcs1 = addlServicesArray[0];
    userPreferences.aAddlSvcs2 = addlServicesArray[1];
    userPreferences.aAddlSvcs3 = addlServicesArray[2];
    userPreferences.aAddlSvcs4 = addlServicesArray[3];
    userPreferences.aAddlSvcs5 = addlServicesArray[4];
    userPreferences.aAddlSvcs6 = addlServicesArray[5];
    userPreferences.aAddlSvcs7 = addlServicesArray[6];
    userPreferences.aAddlSvcs8 = addlServicesArray[7];
    userPreferences.aAddlSvcs9 = addlServicesArray[8];
    userPreferences.aAddlSvcs10 = addlServicesArray[9];
    userPreferences.aAddlSvcs11 = addlServicesArray[10];
    userPreferences.aAddlSvcs12 = addlServicesArray[11];
    userPreferences.aAddlSvcs13 = addlServicesArray[12];
    userPreferences.aAddlSvcs14 = addlServicesArray[13];
```

The problem is that if I only have data in row 0 of the array, by the time it gets to move row 1 it crashes because row 1 is empty.  I'm sure there is a better way of doing this; I have looked at SO and Google, but found nothing specific.  Any help would be appreciated. :-}

Comment: Can you explain some more of the purpose of this code?  What type of data is in the array?  How is the UserPreferences entity defined (any attributes other than the `aAddlSvcsXX` ones)?  How many instances of that entity might there be?

Comment: Strings, all the way around; there are 14 instances of the entity.

Comment: Fourteen instances each with fourteen attributes?  Or one instance with 14 attributes?

Comment: Each attribute contains a unique service, so yes, each is saved to it's own attribute in one (1) entity.

Comment: OK.  Could you either a) have 14 instances each with only one String attribute, or b) store the whole array in 1 attribute on 1 instance?

Comment: No, this is the way it's set up for an existing app and needs to remain... do you have any suggestions which would answer my original question?

Comment: Yes, I'll post a solution - just wanted to check other options first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop.  In the loop, create a string with the name of the attribute, then use the `setValue:forKey:` method:

```
NSUInteger count = [addlServicesArray count];
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<count; i++) {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"aAddlSvcs%lu",i];
    [userPreferences setValue:addlServicesArray[i] forKey:key];
}
```

You should ensure that the array cannot have more entries than there are attributes, otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: Thank you so much... that was it!  I had to make one slight change when creating the string, it's *i+1*, but it works just  like I wanted it to.  :D